# \ref Equation name from \listofmyequations

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, labels

I have a `\listof` `equations` (after the toc) and want to cross-reference with the `\myequation{Ionosphere-free Linear Combination}` not the `\label{iono-free}`. I want to retain the auto-generated numeric label. How do I cross-reference with the `\myequations` name not `\label`?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,fleqn,%
                headinclude,footinclude,parskip=half,%
                numbers=noenddot,cleardoublepage=empty]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[notlof,notlot,notbib]{tocbibind} 
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
%\usepackage[ruled,vlined,algochapter,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of Equations}

\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
    \addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}

\begin{document}

\listofmyequations

\textbf{Equations}

I want to reference the myequations[name here] not the \eqref{iono-free}. 

\begin{equation}
    \label{iono-free}
    \begin{aligned}
        P_{ion-free}= \alpha_{1}  \cdot p_{1} + \alpha_2 \cdot p_{2}\\        
        \phi_{ion-free}= \alpha_{1}  \cdot \varphi_{1} + \alpha_2 \cdot \varphi_{2}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\myequations{Ionosphere-free Linear Combination}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As always on this site, you're more likely to get help if you provide a full but minimal example that others can copy as is and work with.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Are you (re)defining `equation` environments as floats (in the LaTeX sense of the word)? Please clarify what you're actually doing, ideally in the form of a minimum working example, as already suggested by @daleif.

Comment: Please also clarify why you're apparently unwilling to reuse the text string that's employed in the argument of `\myequations` in the argument of `\label`.